# Can I distribute an iOS app OTA (over-the-air) with a Development profile for beta-testing?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am able to generate an IPA + manifest file pair to distribute in-house any iOS app over-the-air using an Ad-hoc distribution profile.

Can I do the same thing with a Development Provisioning profile?

(I tried it but I get the well-known error message in Safari: "Your Application could not be downloaded at this time." and I don't see any relevant information on the device's console - I'm starting to think that the problem is that the App is signed with a Development profile).

Comment: Have you added the UDID properly to your profile?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have also manually downloaded the IPA file, unzipped it and I checked that the UDID is included in the embedded.mobileprovision file inside of the ProvisionedDevices section.